# JSF facelet verifying if condition is true

Tags: java, jsf

I'm trying to implement a composite component which will display the comments form an Array List.

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.List" required="true" shortDescription="The list of objects that should be displayed"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <ui:repeat var="comment" value="#{cc.attrs.commentList}">
        <div class = "comment-block">
            <h3>#{comment.title}</h3>
            <h4>#{comment.author}</h4>
            <p>#{comment.body}</p>
            <h:link outcome = "editComment?id={comment.id}" value = "edit" />
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>

</cc:implementation>
```

Now the problem is that the  tag should be displayed only if the logged user is the author of the comment. Normally I would do this like:

```
<c:if test = "${comment.authId == authUser.id}">
    <a href = "editComment.jsp?id=${comment.id}">
</c:if>
```

How can I do something like this in JSF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of JSF components have the attribute `rendered` in which you can put an EL expression that returns either true or false. Based on the return value, the component will be rendered or not. In your case, you can try this:

```
<h:link rendered="${comment.authId == authUser.id}" 
        outcome = "editComment" value = "edit">
   <f:param name="id" value="#{comment.id}" />
<h:link>
```

Comment: Actually all JSF components have this attribute since it is defined in javax.faces.component.UIComponent.

Comment: And I suppose that the same method I should use if I want to display different components for different url parameters right? Example: for mysite.com/user.xhtml?action=view or mysite.com/user.xhtml?action=edit

Comment: @TGM I have just updated my answer to use `<f:param>` tag. In the future, you can re-use the above code for different URLs. You just need to modify the `outcome` and the list of `<f:param>` to fit your requirement.